# Using pyenv in Ansible

Tags: vagrant, ansible, pyenv

I'm using Ansible to set up Ubuntu-based Vagrant and DigitalOcean boxes, and want to use pyenv to manage environments for a few different websites.

I'm having a problem with permissions when trying to install a version of python using the pyenv I've installed, which is probably down to my lack of basic *nix knowledge.

I have a `deploy` user and group, who I've installed pyenv for, but obviously something's up with which user's doing things as the final task below fails (all variables replaced with strings for clarity):

```
- name: Install pyenv
  git:
    repo: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git
    dest: "/home/deploy/.pyenv"

- name: Install pyenv-virtualenv plugin
  git:
    repo: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv.git
    dest: "/home/deploy/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv"

- name: Add path etc to .bashrc.
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/home/deploy/.bashrc"
    state: present
    create: yes
    line: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"'
    - 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"'
    - 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"'
    - 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"'

- name: Ensure .pyenv permissions are set properly
  file: path=/home/deploy/.pyenv
        recurse=yes
        owner=deploy
        group=deploy
        state=directory

- name: Install default python version
  become: yes
  become_user: 'deploy'
  shell: . /home/deploy/.bashrc && pyenv install 3.5.1
    creates="/home/deploy/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1"
```

When doing `vagrant up` it goes fine until:

> TASK [python : Install default python version] *********************************
>   fatal: [192.168.33.15]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ". /home/deploy/.bashrc && pyenv install 3.5.1", "delta": "0:00:00.002111", "end": "2016-02-16 11:48:26.930971", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2016-02-16 11:48:26.928860", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: pyenv: not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}

**UPDATE:** In case it's important, in this instance (the Vagrant box) my `vagrant.yml` playbook is setting `remote_user` to `vagrant`:

```
- name: Create a virtual machine via vagrant
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  remote_user: vagrant
  ...
```

**UPDATE 2:** If I ssh into the Vagrant VM as the `deploy` user then I can use `pyenv` OK. If I ssh in as `vagrant` and then `sudo -u deploy bash -i` I get `pyenv: command not found`...

**UPDATE 3:** The root of the problem *might* be that neither `/home/deploy/.bashrc` or `/home/deploy/.profile` are sourced when switching to the `deploy` user with `sudo` (tested by `echo`ing from each file), but are when logging in as `deploy`. But, I think `/home/deploy/.bashrc` *is* being sourced by the failing task - echo'd text appears in stdout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As your error is:

> > pyenv: not found

just try simply to use absoulute path to pyenv in your task. This is a recommended way to handle `shell` tasks anyway:

Log in to your machine and find out the path to `pyenv`

```
which pyenv
```

then change your task to

```
 # /path/to/pyenv is the result of the previous command
 ... 
 shell: . /home/deploy/.bashrc && /path/to/pyenv install 3.5.1
 ...
```

Comment: Such a simple thing! Thank you so much. I've spent a day struggling with this. I changed that line to `shell: . /home/deploy/.bashrc && /home/deploy/.pyenv/libexec/pyenv install 3.5.1` and it works. Thanks again.